# how to append html element via jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i used jquery to append html content with onclick function from jquery , but my content doesn't render properly , please help me to fix this.

my code is

```
 $.each(_fileName, function (i, item) {
                imgTag += "<div class='DivColumn-6'>";
                imgTag += "<img src=" + _ImgPath + "Icons/" + _fileName[i]['SenIcon'] + ".jpg class='imgSenIcons'/>";

                imgTag += "<span class='spnSensorName' onclick=calSensorPage('" + _fileName[i]['SenFnCal'];
                imgTag += "','" + _fileName[i]['SensorNmtxt'];
                imgTag += ");>" + _fileName[i]['SensorNmtxt'];
                imgTag += "</span></div>";
            });

            $("#divSensorMnu").append(imgTag);
```

Out is render like this :

```
<span class="spnSensorName" onclick="calSensorPage('CamshaftPosition','CAMSHAFT" position="" sensor);="">CAMSHAFT POSITION SENSOR</span>
```

[image]

I need output like this.

```
 <span class="spnSensorName" onclick="calSensorPage('CamshaftPosition','CAMSHAFT position sensor')">CAMSHAFT POSITION SENSOR</span>
```

i know some missing quotes. please help me to fix.

sorry for my english.

thanks

Comment: `imgTag += "');>" + _fileName[i]['SensorNmtxt'];`, You missed closing quote

Comment: Not working....

Comment: Could you please provide a sample of the values within the `_fileName` array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is due to your use of mis-matching and un-escaped quotes within the `span` string you generate. Try this:

```js
var _fileName = [{
  "Sno": 1,
  "SensorNmtxt": "RAIL PRESSURE SENSOR",
  "SenFnCal": "RailPressure",
  "SenIcon": 1
}];

var imgTag = '', _ImgPath = "/";

$.each(_fileName, function(i, item) {
  imgTag += "<div class='DivColumn-6'>";
  imgTag += "<img src=" + _ImgPath + "Icons/" + _fileName[i]['SenIcon'] + ".jpg class='imgSenIcons'/>";
  
  imgTag += '<span class="spnSensorName" onclick="calSensorPage(\'' + _fileName[i]['SenFnCal'];
  imgTag += '\',\'' + _fileName[i]['SensorNmtxt'];
  imgTag += '\')";>' + _fileName[i]['SensorNmtxt'];
  imgTag += '</span></div>';
});

$("#divSensorMnu").append(imgTag);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divSensorMnu"></div>
```

However you should note that using `on*` event attributes is a very outdated approach, and makes the HTML and associated JS code a mess to work with - as you can see from the concatenation nightmare above.

A much better solution is to store the required metadata in the element using `data` attributes and add an unobtrusive event handler, something like this:

```js
var _fileName = [{
  "Sno": 1,
  "SensorNmtxt": "RAIL PRESSURE SENSOR",
  "SenFnCal": "RailPressure",
  "SenIcon": 1
}]
var _ImgPath = "/";

var html = _fileName.map(function(item) {
  return `<div class="DivColumn-6"><img src="${_ImgPath}Icons/${item.SenIcon}.jpg class="imgSenIcons"/><span class="spnSensorName" data-fncal="${item.SenFnCal}">${item.SensorNmtxt}</span></div>`;
});
$("#divSensorMnu").append(html);

$('.spnSensorName').click(function() {
  var $el = $(this)
  var fncal = $el.data('fncal');
  var nmtxt = $el.text();
  console.log(fncal, nmtxt);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divSensorMnu"></div>
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 1):

try this

**demo**:https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XEwzaN

```
var SensorNmtxt = "CAMSHAF position sensor";
var SenFnCal = "CamshaftPosition";


var  imgTag = "<div class='DivColumn-6'>";
imgTag += '<img src=123Icons/123.jpg class="imgSenIcons"/>';
imgTag += '<span class="spnSensorName" onclick="calSensorPage(\'' + SenFnCal + '\',\'' + SensorNmtxt + '\')">' + SensorNmtxt;
imgTag += '</span></div>';

$("#divSensorMnu").append(imgTag);
console.log(imgTag)


function calSensorPage (){
  console.log("hi")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi here is your corrected js you're missing a ' right here i added it, because you were missing it it didn't finish the onclick tag :

```
   imtTag += '<span class="spnSensorName" onclick="calSensorPage(\'' + _fileName[i]['SenFnCal'];
   imgTag += '\',\'' + _fileName[i]['SensorNmtxt'];
   imgTag += '\');">' + _fileName[i]['SensorNmtxt'];
   imgTag += '</span></div>';
```

Just change all you double quote by simple and add " " for onclick method

Comment: var Sensors =[
 {
   "Sno": 1,
   "SensorNmtxt": "RAIL PRESSURE SENSOR",
   "SenFnCal": "RailPressure",
   "SenIcon": 1
 }];

Comment: I have updated the solution can yo utell me if it's working for you ?